# How to get Textview reference using butterknif in android

Tags: android, butterknife

Hi in my layout there is I have included sub layout using ButterKnife in Android. How can I get TextView reference my code is below. Same thing, I want to get with help of ButterKnife, can someone help me please...

### gmail_view.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gmail_item"
        android:title="gmail_count"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/badge_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

### badge_layout:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gmail_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="bell" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gmail_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="17sp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/gmail_icon"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/gmail_icon"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bage_circle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Activity:-

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.gmail_item);
RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menuItem.getActionView();
gmail_text = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.gmail_textview);
```

Comment: @Bind(R.id.btnid_given_inlayout)

Comment: no no i have layout and it's included sub layout

Comment: @Nullable @BindView(R.id.might_not_be_there) TextView mightNotBeThere;

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Bind(R.id.btnid_given_inlayout) 
     Button btn;

     @Bind(R,id.LAYOUTID)
     RelativeLayout layout;

 in oncreate u need bo bind the views...

so after setting content 

 write the below line 

ButterKnife.bind(this);

        in code...u can refer like...

      btn.setOnclickListener.
       layout.setVisibility();
```

if it doesnt answer ur question ,u can post ur xml

Comment: i posted xml file please see once

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code -

```
gmail_text = (TextView) ButterKnife.findById(badgeLayout, R.id.gmail_textview);
```

Comment: @BindView(R.id.gmail_item)MenuItem menuItem; when i bind this menuitem throwing exception

Comment: I don't think you need to have `@BindView(R.id.gmail_item)MenuItem menuItem;` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
  action_save:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_save1"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Save"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

```
in   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)

  inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_save, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_save1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

ButterKnife won't supporting binding MenuItem, as in the [ButterKnife issue #41](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/41).

---

**No**, you can't bind the menu layout view because ButterKnife only binds the layout in activity `onCreate`  or fragment `onCreateView` method. ButterKnife will complains about not founding the view because the Menu is inflated **after** onCreate() which is in `onCreateOptionsMenu` like the following code:

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
  return true;
}
```

Here the diagram that shows the Activity lifecyle diagram from [android-lifecycle](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle):

[image]
So you **can't** bind the view with ButterKnife.

CMIIW